# How i can find out which is the latest revision number in the repository?

Tags: linux, svn, command-line, repository

How i can find out which is the latest revision number in the repository?

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking. You should improve that, before it will get closed for not being a real question.

Comment: do you mean "svn info" command

Comment: Please clarify the information you're hoping to get from subversion.

Comment: Oh i'm so so sorry ..... i mean i want to know the latest revision of repository

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`svn info` (or `svn st`) will tell you the current revision of your working copy. `svn st -u` will tell you the latest revision at the repository (and which files differ from your working copy). Use `svn help status` to learn more.